Relocating a ELF in a freestanding env
Well I am making an OS and I want to make my Programs/Kernel elf's but I want them relocated so that I can protect programs more to memory editing.
I did not yet try something because I don't know where to start so if somebody knows something please tell me
I did look on the osdev wiki and also asked chatgpt but those were not helpful I tried looking trough the elf for a easy way to do it but I did not know for what to look this is my last option. So if you can help me please do so.

What code is actually taking your ELF and mapping/copying it into memory? If it's your own code, you're going to have to do the relocation; in that case please take a look at this question and its answers as a starting point to see how ELF relocations are handled - you'll have to do something similar in your own loader. It's not a perfect fit of an answer for this question (hence not marking it as duplicate), but it may at least shed some more general light on the relocations you'll encounter and what you'll need to handle.
